# Favouriting a question never completes

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, ios-app

I'm running 0.1.17. When attempting to "Favorite" a question, the loading spinner showing "Favoriting" shows, but nothing happens...

The loading icon spins indefinitely, and the question never shows up in my favorite list.

Comment: Got it.  Will take a look at what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll be fixed in the next build. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! That was quick!

Comment: Possible regression in 0.1.19. Says "error: question is already favorited", but is 
not. Works on websit