# Favoriting produces "Question is already favorited" - regressed in iOS App 0.1.19

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bookmarks, ios-app

Related: [Favouriting a question never completes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221862/favouriting-a-question-never-completes)

When trying to favorite a question in the latest alpha, I get the following

[image]

The previous bug was reported in 0.1.17, fixed in 0.1.18, and appears to have regressed in 0.1.19

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: huh. well that's funny, neither can I! It was so consistent when I posted this. No new version either. Maybe it was a network hiccup, or a quick silently fixed API bug? I'll go ahead and mark my own question norepro :)

Comment: never mind, I just tried to. I guess status-norepro is your job :)